# jQuery .each function across browsers (works in ff, ie8, not ie7)

Tags: jquery-selectors

I've been messing with this for far too long, and managed to get IE8 working, but IE7 has me stumped.

I've got a table, and for each column, I am trying to extract a number of divs. I am only extracting divs which match specific selectors, not all divs in the column.
My original jquery selector was

```
jQuery('div.a1, div.a3, div.a4, div.a7','table#a'+tableId+' td:nth-child('+columnNum+')').each(function(){
alert(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
});
```

This worked great in FF, but didn't trigger the .each function at all in IE.

After messing around for a bit, I got to

```
jQuery('td:nth-child('+columnNum+') > div.a1, td:nth-child('+columnNum+') > div.a3, td:nth-child('+columnNum+') > div.a4,td:nth-child('+columnNum+') >  div.a7', table#a+'tableId).each(function(){
alert(jQuery(this.attr('id'));
});
```

Not so nice, but works in IE8. 
I had tried all sorts of combinations using .eq(+'columnNum+') but nothing else was working.

Now I go and test in IE7, and again the .each isn't being triggered.

What is the nicest way (and cross-browser compatible) to work with this sort of .each element?

--------------addition--------------

After further testing and playing around with suggestions from DrJ and bdukes, I've found that the table#'+tableId breaks the function in both IE7&8.

I've gone back to my original code

```
jQuery('div.a1, div.a3, div.a4, div.a7','table#a'+tableId+' td:nth-child('+columnNum+')').each(function(){
alert(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
});
```

as that seems to me the most efficient. 
If I remove 'table#a'+tableId, i get the correct response in all browsers, except that it is adding up the results from all tables, and I need to be able to get only the results from one table at a time. 
I have also tried 'table#a'+tableId+'>td:nth-child('+columnNum+')').each, but that doesn't work either.

The first function i've used works perfectly in firefox.

----------------the html being selected---------------------------
The tables are being created dynamically in javascript so I can't really copy and past it, but here is what the output looks like. It ends up looking kinda like a gantt chart on a table.

```
<table id="a1">
 <tr>
  <th colspan="5">
        Group Name
   </th>
   </tr>
  <tr class="rowId1" >
  <td>
   <div class="a1" id="a43" style="margin-left:13px; width:60px" ></div>
   </td>
  <td>
  </td>
   <td>
    <div class="a3" id="a93" style="margin-left:4px; width: 80px" ></div>
   <div class="a2" id="a94" style="margin-left:4px; width: 30px" ></div>
  </td>
 <td>
    <div class="a1" id="a24" style="margin-left: 15px; width: 65px;" ></div>
  </td>
 <td>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </tr>
  <tr class="rowId1" >
  <td>
   <div class="a7" id="a24" style="margin-left:10px; width:60px" ></div>
   </td>
  <td>
 <div class="a2" id="a15" style="margin-left:14px; width: 22px" ></div>
  </td>
   <td>
   ;
   <div class="a2" id="a105" style="margin-left: 8px; width: 50px" ></div>
  </td>
 <td>
  </td>
 <td>
<div class="a4" id="a102" style="margin-left: 5px; width: 45px;" ></div>
  </td>
 </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: are you sure it's not because you're missing 2 closing parentheses (')') in line 2? jQuery.each() works fine on IE6/7 normally.

Comment: Thanks DrJ
No, that is not the issue. That was just a typing mistake.

Comment: I would guess that it's more of an issue with your selector than the `each` function.  Make sure that you're actually selecting what you expect in each browser, break each section down and see if you can find out where it's getting the wrong values.

Comment: Oh yes, as far as I remember, on IE if you put whitespace before or after > in selectors it doesn't work. Try "td:nth-child('+columnNum+')>div.a3" instead.

Comment: @bdukes - if the case where an issue with the selectors, then wouldn't I have the same issue with each browser? how can the selectors be different from one browser to the next?

Comment: DrJ-I've tried without whitespace around the >, and that didn't work. .each does work in IE7 with whitespace around the >. Apparently what is breaking it is the table#'+tableId. I'm updating the question to reflect this

Comment: Can we see the HTML this is trying to select?

Comment: I wouldn't think that a selector _should_ be different between browsers, but you may have found a bug.  What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I hadn't considered the jQuery version bdukes. I was using 1.4.0, just tried 1.4.1, and same issue. went back to 1.3.2, but the page doesn't load completely, and I get no errors in firebug (which is kinda weird).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was an issue with IE failing when two different elements have the same ID. Apparently this breaks the .each function.

I had two tables 
table.notes#a1 & table.inputs#a1

The .each function should have gone through each table but instead found neither.

jQuery also wouldn't run in ie with

```
jQuery('div.a1, div.a3, div.a4, div.a7','table.inputs#a'+tableId+' td:nth-child('+columnNum+')').each(function(){
alert(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
});
```

which it should have done, as I am them pointing directly to a specific table even if the id is not unique.

I'm using id's retrieved from the database for the id, and IE doesn't like id's that start with numbers, so I just added an 'a' to the beginning of the id. 
However, it apparently doesn't like that either, so now I'm adding the first letter of the class and then the '1' or whatever the id number is.

This solves the issue.